# Improperly Configured Form - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Recently, I've figure out how to create a registration in Django. The problem is that there are just three fields - `username`,`password` and it's confirmation.

In my project, there will be at least two types of `users` with different attributes. `Customers` and `Freelancers`. So I've tried to make new model as I've found here on StackOverflow, but it returns Exception:

```
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form UserCreateForm needs updating.
```

**MODELS.PY:**

```
class UserCustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
          return "%s's profile" % self.user
```

**FORMS.PY:**

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and UserProfile without database save")
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user_profile = UserCustomerProfile(user=user, email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        user_profile.save()
        return user, user_profile
```

**VIEWS.PY:**

```
def register(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = UserCustomerProfile(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return HttpResponseRedirect('register/complete/')

     else:
         form = UserCreateForm()
     token = {}
     token.update(csrf(request))
     token['form'] = form

     return render_to_response('register/registration_form.html', token)
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Partially off-topic, but do you really need to limit your user model at all? Its entirely possible that someone may want to both solicit and freelance and from what I can tell is they would need two models at the minute

Comment: @Sayse Maybe not, but I'm new in Django and I try my best. The point is that the most simple way to create registration form was to use the built in functions. Then I've realized that there are two types of users - Freelancers - Translators and Customers. For Translator, I want for example to know, which language translates but I don't want this information about customer. If there is a better way, it would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form UserCreateForm needs updating.

Try e.g.:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but there is a one problem. It rewrites username form with email form. Is there an option to have both of them in registration form?

Comment: Im not sure, if i understand you correctly. But if you want username and email in the form, you want to put `fields=['username', 'email',]`. Please see the docs to this for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **"fields" attribute** to **"Meta" inner class** in **"UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm)" class** as shown below:

**FORMS.PY:**

```py
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email") 
        # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑   
    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and UserProfile without database save")
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user_profile = UserCustomerProfile(user=user, email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        user_profile.save()
        return user, user_profile
```

Or, You need to add **"exclude" attribute** to **"Meta" inner class** in **"UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm)" class** as shown below:

**FORMS.PY:**

```py
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("first_name", "last_name")
        # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑
    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and UserProfile without database save")
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user_profile = UserCustomerProfile(user=user, email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        user_profile.save()
        return user, user_profile
```